# place a button on intersections of tables in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to place a button element on the intersections of a table for a gomoku game that I am working on. So far, I only know how to place a button INSIDE a table block but not on the intersection itself.

[Current Gomoku Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ2eZ.png)

^ I want the blue button to appear on the intersection of the table.

[Button on intersection of the board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q100h.png)

Comment: Can you show some basic HTML and CSS for what you have now, and perhaps a sketch of what you're trying to do, and an explanation as to why?

Comment: So, what you have isn't really a table.  It's a game board?  I'd recommend SVG for this instead.  Then, you can place whatever wherever you want it, and still have control with JavaScript and what not.